# Ref. Shallow heap showing very high value in MAT

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am first time using MAT, i have gone through Google I/O video for memory management. But, now when it comes to practical, i am seeing a column name `Ref. Shallow Heap` in `merge shortest path to GC roots(Exclude weak reference)`.
One of my application component is showing very high value in this column. So, please tell me what does it signify and how it is different from `shallow heap`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: what is the differences between shallow and retained heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707572/android-what-is-the-differences-between-shallow-and-retained-heap)

Comment: @CommonsWare It is not duplicate of that question because, i want to know details for `Ref. shallow heap` as i can see three different column in MAT, one for `shallow heap`, other for `Retained heap` and third one is `Ref. shallow heap`. This third column area of my interest. Are `shallow heap` and `ref shallow heap` same/similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the description of shallow vs retained heap here
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/concepts/shallowretainedheap.html

furthermore see the explanation specific to your question here
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/210895/