# Continuous Memory Allocation Not Causing Leakage

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, jvm

I'm trying to simulate an OutOfMemory exception in Android. My method is basically having a static ArrayList keep adding `long[2048]` arrays.

I had the program running for a while and it collected 685 instances of `long[2048]`. Using Android Studio's 3.0 profiler, the heap dump looks as such:

```
| class name | alloc count | shallow size | retained size |
| ---------- | ----------- | ------------ | ------------- |
| long[]     | 685         | 9997168      | 9997168       |
```

So, the memory is NOT getting garbage collected. Regardless, the app's heap memory remains at 40Mb and doesn't drop down.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the app be leaking memory like there is no tomorrow now?? What trick does the JVM do this time?

Also, what is the difference between `shallow size`, and `retained size`?

P.S: Here is the code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static List<long[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myList.add(loadStuff());
            }
        });
    }


    static long[] loadStuff() {
        return new long[2048];
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the question. It is in fact leaking memory, why are you saying it's not?

Comment: Because Android Studio 3.0 memory profiler shows the total app memory remains since the beginning at 40mb. It gets a bit higher, but the garbage collector kicks in and returns it back to 40mb.

Comment: In your onClick add a loop to do that like `100000` times and click a couple of times :)

Comment: I guess that would definitely throw an exception, but my question is why is the app not doing throwing that when its "slowly" leaking.

Comment: You would need to click a lot to get `OutOfMemory`, 700 clicks is like 10mb, depends on your phone, but I bet you are gonna need more than that. That will eventually happen tho, that memory is not getting garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

shallow size is the memory that is occupied right now whereas the retained size is the size that will be freed after collecting garbage see reference in here

[shallow vs retained size](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Fconcepts%2Fshallowretainedheap.html)

Comment: Understood: I'll also link a lengthier answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707572/android-what-is-the-differences-between-shallow-and-retained-heap